Spring batch reader large dataset
I have following reader. I need to read 10 K records at a time so I set the fetchsize to 10 K but how I can make sure if I have large data set to read from database my reader shouldn't throw connection time out error. Do I need to implement reader in a way to get the connection, read it and close the connection to get away from time out error?
    @Component
    public class Reader1 extends JdbcCursorItemReader<Entity1> {
        private static final String query = "SELECT t2.*, t1.id FROM table2 t2, table1 t1 WHERE t1.id = t2.inputId";
    
        public Reader1(DataSource dataSource) {
            setName(getClass().getSimpleName());
            setDataSource(dataSource);
            setSql(query);
            setFetchSize(10000);
            setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Entity1.class));
        }
    
    }
    
    @Bean(name="Step1")
        public Step Step1(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) throws IOException {
            return new StepBuilder("Step1", jobRepository).<Entity1, Entity1>chunk(chunkSize, transactionManager)
                    .reader(readItems())
                    .writer(writeItems())
                    .listener(writeListener())
                    .build();
        }

@Bean
    public ItemReader<Entity1> readItems() {
        Reader1 reader1 = new Reader1(datasource);
        return reader1;
    }

    @Bean
    public JsonFileItemWriter<Entity1> writeItems() throws IOException {
     
        return new JsonFileItemWriterBuilder<Entity1>()
                .jsonObjectMarshaller(new JacksonJsonObjectMarshaller<>())
                .resource(new FileSystemResource(filePath))
                .name("jsonFileItemWriter")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WriteListener writeListener() {
        JdbcTemplate  jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(datasource);
        WriteListener writeListener = new WriteListener(jdbcTemplate);

        return writeListener;
    }

